# How to use if/else condition for flashlight switch?

Tags: ios, uiswitch

So I have a UISwitch for my overlay, which appears every time the camera comes up. Now when I switch the on button or slide the switch to the right(on mode) the flashlight turns on. But when I switch it to the left, it does not turn off. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)mySwitchPressed {
    if (self.mySwitch.on) { 
        AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice
        defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight
            isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
            BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if(success) {
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        } else {
            AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice
            defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight 
                isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
                BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
                if(success) {
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                    [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code reformatted, it seems that your `else` clause is in the wrong place. Try moving the `else` to after the end of the first `if` block:

```
- (void)mySwitchPressed {
    if (self.mySwitch.on) { 
        AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice
        defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight
            isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
            BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if(success) {
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    } else {
        AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice
        defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight 
            isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
            BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if(success) {
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked like divine intervention. Thank you good sir. What's the logic behind it though?

Comment: Before your outermost `if` statement did not have an `else` clause. Because of this, all of the code inside the function was only run if `self.mySwitch.on` was true. Now, in the event that `self.mySwitch.on` is not true, the code that turns the flashlight off is run.